# Prefill a certain cell with a number when data (a letter) is entered in one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out a VBA code that will allow me to prefill a certain cell with a number when I type in "X" in a cell right next to it. I can't figure out if I should use Range, or Insert, or what.

I cannot use a button and assign a macro to it because I need to see which cells I have put an "X" into.

This is what I have so far, but it's using a button with macro assigned to it:
490 is being entered into E9 and tabs over to F9 after the macro button is clicked:

```
Sub eightNineSpring()
    Range("E9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "490"
    Range("F9").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: so if you input in column E a "x" then you want "490" in column F?

Comment: Do you need a macro, or would a formula work?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure what would be easier, a macro or a formula. As long as I can achieve the result, I'm fine with either one. Thank you

Comment: Well @DirkReichel has you covered!

Comment: my comment was exactly the opposite :P (messed up F and E, but it is in the right order for the macro/function)

Comment: because not each row will have an "X" in it.  So if there's no "X" in one of the rows, then I don't need 490 next to it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as automation put in the worksheet you need it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.Value = "x" Then Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = 490
  End If
End Sub
```

or as formula in E1 then copy down

```
=IF(F1="x",490,"")
```

But keep in mind when deleting the "x" (or replace it with something different):
The function will empty the 490 again while the change event will not

Comment: Does the `Target.Count = 1` make sure that he only changes one cell? If he highlighted F1:F10 and entered "Dirk" with `CTRL+ENTER`, this wouldn't fire, correct?

Comment: thats correct... doing it for a range would need to loop all cells in range... and I wanted to keep it simple :)

Comment: @BruceWayne While entering "Dirk" it would never trigger the 490 :P

Answer (score 2):

When using a Change Events that makes a change, `Application.Events` should be turned off to avoid the code calling itself recursively.

The code below caters for one or more cells in E1:E10 being updated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("F1:F10"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rng2 In Range
    If rng2.Value = "x" Then rng2.Offset(0, -1).Value = 490
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: While it would not be the big deal to not turn off the events, cus the the range to trigger a real action doesn't intersect with the range which is manipulated... so each recursive call would end at the check and do nothing at all... but to do it in a clean way, turning off is not optional... :)

Comment: @DirkReichel it is poor practice to leave a change event uncontrolled .... small change to the code and ongoing recursion may cause a crash.